# Opening PDFs in a container using dreamweaver and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, dreamweaver

[image]

I am using the jQuery accordion feature in the new Dreamweaver. What I want to do is be able to select on an account and open a corresponding PDF for that account.

I am trying to figure out how to link a PDF with an account and have it open in the "content goes here" Container when an account is selected.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link href="jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.core.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.accordion.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="jQueryAssets/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jQueryAssets/jquery-ui-1.9.2.accordion.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<body>

<div id="container" style="width:700">

<div id="header" style="background-color:#FFA500;">
<h1 style="margin-bottom:0;">jQuery Test File</h1></div>


<div id="menu" style="background-color:#FFD700;height:278;width:300;float:left;">
  <b>Utilities</b><br> 

<div id="Accordion1">
  <h3><a href="#"> Electric </a></h3>
  <div>    3201 New Mexico AV</br>     
<br>
4200 Wisconsin Ave</br>
<br>
4545 42nd St NW 312 <br>
4545 42nd St 309</br></div>
  <h3><a href="#"> Gas </a></h3>
  <div>Anderson Hall<br>
Asbury Bldg</br>
<br>
Asbury Boiler Distribution <br>
Beeghly Bldg.</div>
  <h3><a href="#">Water</a></h3>
  <div>3500 Nebraska Ave. NW
    <br>
3501 Nebraska Ave. NW<br>
4629 Rockwood Pkwy <br>
4745 Massachusetts Ave</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $( "#Accordion1" ).accordion(); 
});
</script>

<div id="footer" style="background-color:#FFA500;clear:both;text-align:center;"></div>

</div>

<div id="content" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;height:278px;width:400px;float:left;">
Content goes here</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The only thing I can think of that would work would be to use HTML frames, and I refuse to recommend that.

Comment: By the way, you should *really* move all those inline CSS styles into a separate stylesheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) This has nothing to do with Dreamweaver, it's only a code editor.

2) Use an Iframe.

```
<a href="myfile.pdf" target="viewframe">3501 Nebraska Ave. NW</a>

<iframe name="viewframe" style="display:block;height:400px;"></iframe>
```